# Pandas: Trouble Updating Rows Conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>>df
     rtt   requests
asn  
1000 4000  100
2000 50    NaN
3000 18000 300
```

My goal is to divide `rtt` by `requests` in place **if** `requests` is not `NaN`, otherwise leave `rtt` untouched. I've tried various things and either the second row gets set to `NaN` like so:

```
>>>df
     rtt   requests
asn  
1000 40    100
2000 NaN   NaN
3000 60    300
```

Or the DataFrame isn't updated at all

### Desired Final Output

```
>>>df
     rtt   requests
asn  
1000 40    100
2000 50    NaN
3000 60    300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fillna`

```
In [1889]: df['rtt'] = df['rtt'].div(df['requests']).fillna(df['rtt'])

In [1890]: df
Out[1890]:
       rtt  requests
asn
1000  40.0     100.0
2000  50.0       NaN
3000  60.0     300.0
```

Or, `/` instead of `div`

```
In [1895]: (df['rtt'] / df['requests']).fillna(df['rtt'])
Out[1895]:
asn
1000    40.0
2000    50.0
3000    60.0
dtype: float64
```

Or, `combine_first`

```
In [1897]: df['rtt'].div(df['requests']).combine_first(df['rtt'])
Out[1897]:
asn
1000    40.0
2000    50.0
3000    60.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I got three good answers back to back, so I had to pick the best one. I started by doing a quick performance test of all the answers, but they were all identical performance. I ultimately settled on this answer because it provided the answer with the shortest code: `df.rtt = (df.rtt / df.requests).fillna(df.rtt)` -- this requires the least typing and is still very explicit and easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Or using np.where

```
df['rtt'] = np.where(df['requests'].notnull(), df['rtt']/df['requests'], df['rtt'])


        rtt requests
asn     
1000    40.0    100.0
2000    50.0    NaN
3000    60.0    300.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, `div` with `fill_value=1`:

```
df.assign(rtt = df.rtt.div(df.requests, fill_value=1))
```

Output:

```
       rtt  requests
asn                 
1000  40.0     100.0
2000  50.0       NaN
3000  60.0     300.0
```